# JavaScript Stack Management/Freeing up memory

Tags: javascript, performance

When defining a class as such:

```
var namespace = {};
namespace.appleClass = function() {
   this.collection = [];
};

namespace.appleClass.prototype.methodOne = function(arg) {
   this.collection.push(arg);
};
```

The way to get rid of this.collection is simple.

```
this.collection.length = 0;
```

My question is what happens to the methods defined above (on `namespace.appleClass.prototype`). How does JavaScript deal with them? Where is a function 'stored'? How can that storage be freed up?

The above class can be used as such.

```
var apple = new appleClass();
appleClass.methodOne(2);
appleClass.collection[0]// will be equal to two etc..
```

**I know how to null DOM references, COM references and the long story behind the delete operator. What I don't know is what is the best way to delete functions and references to them from a 'custom prototype' or 'class' to say so.**

Comment: Your functions should be inside prototypes where they don't get replicated. Why it isn't your case?

Comment: Do not deal with memory in javascript. As long as you don't create circular references, the garbage collector knows what to do.

Comment: @JanDvorak: His function is on a prototype (`namespace.appleClass.prototype`).

Comment: @ alex23: *"My question is what happens to methods defined within them."* What methods are you talking about?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder then they won't get cloned and hog memory.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Hence my question to alex23 above. :-)

Comment: ***Please*** don't post and run, it's disrespectful of people's time and energy. If the question is worth asking, it's worth sticking around for a few minutes to address questions and clarifications people ask for.

Comment: @alex23: So ask the question when you have time to respond to queries on it. Re your questions, I've updated my answer to address them, hope that helps!

Comment: my answer didn't help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The way to get rid of this.collection is simple.
>
> ```
> this.collection.length = 0;
> ```

That doesn't get rid of the array, that just truncates it so it has no entries. To actually get rid of the array entirely, do `delete this.collection` (which will remove the property referring to the array entirely, making the array eligible for garbage collection) or `this.collection = null` (which will release the reference to the array, making it eligible for garbage collection, but *not* remove the property, which will still exist with the value `null`).

Anything that was in `this.collection` and which isn't referred to elsewhere will then be eligible for garbage collection. When (or indeed whether) this happens is entirely down to the JavaScript implementation.

And that's the key point, really: To "manage" memory in JavaScript, you just make sure nothing is referring to the thing you don't want anymore. Usually that falls out of your application logic anyway (you don't want it anymore, so you drop your references to it). If you design your code keeping in mind [how closures work](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html), for the most part, you don't need to worry about memory management.

Re your questions in the comments on the question:

> I am taking about the methods found under `namespace.appleClass.prototype`. How does JavaScript deal with them? Where is a function 'stored'? How can that storage be freed up?

The function object is stored in heap (almost certainly; if it were only referenced by a local variable, some engines like Google's V8 might well use stack for it); where the code is is implementation-dependent. A reference to the function object (and therefore to its code) is stored in the property on the `prototype` object on `appleClass`. There is only one of these functions, which is shared by all instances created by `new namespace.appleClass` via the prototype chain. There is **not** a separate copy of the function for each instance (just a separate reference to it), and thus there is no need to worry about "cleaning up" that function on instances.

If you no longer need that function **at all**, anywhere in your code (e.g., **all** `appleClass` instances no longer need it), you can get rid of it via `delete namespace.appleClass.prototype.methodOne`). That will remove the property from the prototype, which releases its reference to the function object, which releases its reference to the function code, all of which are then eligible for garbage collection. But this would be very unusual, and a single function doesn't take up much memory in any case.

Comment: @alex23: I've updated the answer to address your questions from the comments on the question. Re the `length` property vs. setting the property to `null` or deleting it: Your assertion that that is more efficient doesn't make sense, since setting the `length` to `0` results in a series of property delete operations (and so just a single `delete this.collection` disconnecting the entire object graph should be at least as efficient). As an extraordinary claim, it would require extraordinary evidence. :-)

Comment: @alex23: Glad that helped. *"The logic: I thought it would free up all the items in the collection without destroying the collection itself."* Yup, that's exactly what it does. *"So it would be a more efficient way of doing collection = []"* Quite likely, yes. If you're going to reuse the collection, absolutely setting `length` to `0` would be how I would approach it.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a variable to `null` makes sure to break any references to objects in all browsers including circular references being made between the DOM elements and Javascript scopes.
By using `delete` command we are marking objects to be cleared on the next run of the Garbage collection, but if there are multiple variables referencing the same object, deleting a single variable WILL NOT free the object, it will just remove the linkage between that variable and the object. And on the next run of the Garbage collection, only the variable will be cleaned.